# Parenthesis and asterisk in Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

In Objective C I know that the asterisk * works as a pointer to creating/defining/initializing a pointer to an object.

But what about when the asterisk is inside a parenthesis?

It is the same

(NSString*) name;

than

NSString *name;

Second question

If I declare in the @ interface the methods without using @property way i do

```
  - (void) setName:(NSString*) newName;
  - (NSString*) name;
  - (void) setSupervisor:(Employee*) newSupervisor;
  - (Employee*) supervisor;
  - (void) setSalary:(int) newSalary;
  - (int) salary;
```

But if i use @property I do

```
   @property (nonatomic, readonly) int employeeNumber;
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name; 
   @property (nonatomic, retain) Employee *supervisor;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) int salary;
```

Why the parenthesis in NSString, int, Employee disappeared?
Why the asterisk move from (NSString*) name;
to
NSString *name

Thank you

CL

Comment: Question number two:  It's just the way the language syntax is defined.  There is no "why" other than to make it easier for the parser to deal with it at compile time.

Comment: Nice.  A duplicate of your own duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the way Objective C syntax is defined. In both cases it means a pointer to an object. The return arguments from methods must be wrapped in parenthesis in Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
NSString *name;
```

Means creating a pointer to an object called name.

This:

```
- (void) setName:(NSString*) newName;
```

Means that the parameter that the method will receive (newName) will be a pointer to a string

And, by the way, I answered another similar question yesterday to you, maybe it's time to start reading some manuals, or at least accepting some answers.

Comment: Hi Antonio.I'm reading 3 of them and I just get confuse with this move of the asterisk

Comment: Don't worry, we are here to help. Please accept some answers.

Comment: I come from a Mathematical background and parentheses as you are aware are use to prioritize things that's why I thought the answer you gave me yesterday did not apply in this instance. Thanks anyway

Comment: Didn't realise at the beginning, I closed it after it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a parantheses to enclose a class you are doing something called casting. Casting allows you to tell the receiving object that the incoming object is of a certain type. For instance:

```
float f = (float) myInt;
```

Or something more useful like:

```
myCustomViewController = (MyCustomViewControllerClass *)navigationController.topViewController
```

In the case of the `.topViewController`, Xcode will think that it will return a UIViewController and not a `MyCustomViewControllerClass`, so we have to tell Xcode that that is what it's receiving so we can then do class specific method calls. There are other cases where you'll use casting too, like in method declarations which pass parameters. Again, you're telling the compiler that the object being passed through is of a certain type.

When you leave off the parentheses like in:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWith...];
```

you're declaring that the variable is of a certain type, in this case an `NSArray`. You can then `instantiate` that variable and use it. It's important to remember the difference between the two. Whenever you're creating a new variable and want to give it a class, leave off the brackets as above.

For completion, when you see something in square brackets that's a method being called on a class, so `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myString];` is calling a method on the `NSString` class.

I hope this was of some help understanding castings, but for more info google "Objective-C Casting", it's also called "Typecasting". 
Mike

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about casting, but about method declarations.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ok editing for more information.